# A word for someone that loves learning/ curious, has wonder about the world In general

Tags: single-word-requests, literature, literary-english, descriptive-grammar

I need a word that describes the love of learning, discovering, or it could even be a word that describes a curious person.

Answer (score 0):

philomath (ˈfɪləˌmæθ)

Definitions

noun 
a person who enjoys learning new facts and acquiring new knowledge

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/philomath